# only one worker_threads running when i spawned two in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, multithreading, worker-thread

I have this file `analyze-caption-job.ts`

```
async function analyzeCaptionJob(): Promise<void> {
  while (true) {
    console.log("analyzing!");
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));
  }

}

analyzeCaptionJob();
```

And `youtube-metadata-job.ts`

```
async function youtubeMetadataJob(): Promise<void> {
  while (true) {
    console.info("youtubing!");
    await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));
  }
}

youtubeMetadataJob();
```

and a main file `cron.ts`

```
import path from "path";

import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';

const runWorkers = async () => {
  const worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'jobs') + '/analyze-caption-job.ts', {});
    
  const worker2 = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'jobs') + '/youtube-metadata-job.ts', {});
    
}

runWorkers();
```

When I run it with `npx ts-node-dev cron.ts`,

The output is:

```
youtubing!
youtubing!
youtubing!
youtubing!
youtubing!
```

The analyzing! is not printing at all.

However, if I add a 5 sec "pause/sleep" in between the worker initializations. It's fixed. Why is this happening?

```
import path from "path";

import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';

const runWorkers = async () => {
  const worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'jobs') + '/analyze-caption-job.ts', {});

   
+  await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 5000));
  
  const worker2 = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'jobs') + '/youtube-metadata-job.ts', {});
    
}

runWorkers();
```

Output:

```
youtubing!
analyzing!
youtubing!
analyzing!
youtubing!
analyzing!
```

Comment: please call `await analyzeCaptionJob();` and `await youtubeMetadataJob();`

Comment: @shafiq.rst I can't. I get "Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher" error. My project only use commonjs module.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.  Works perfectly fine for me in node v18.16.0.  I get an alternating `youtubing!` and `analyzing!`.  So, as of this moment, it appears that there's no enough info in the question to understand why you're getting the result you're getting.  Your code (converted to plain Javascript and ESM modules) works just fine for me.

Comment: In trying to reproduce the issue with your code, I un-Typescripted it (converted to plain Javascript) and then I had to remove references to `__dirname` because that is not defined in ESM modules.  I ran it as plain ESM modules and it works just fine for me.

Comment: Good call. So actually, it seems like it only doesn't work with ts-node-dev. When I used ts-node, it works fine! Thanks so much @jfriend00!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I saw the exact same problems, and I don't know solution, when you are running code via ts-node-dev.
But I found out, that problem is with `ts-node-dev`, because the same code with "clean" nodejs code is works fine. Yeah, there are problems with file extension ( when we want to use `*.ts` files with worker threads ), but anyway, it works.

```
import path from "path";

import { Worker } from 'worker_threads';

const runWorkers = async () => {
  const worker = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'analyze-caption-job.js'));
  const worker2 = new Worker(path.join(__dirname, 'youtube-metadata-job.js'));

}

runWorkers();
```

Scripts

```
npx tsc # to build
node dist/jobs/cron.js # to run
```